# How to reference other field/matric with Quality gate

Tags: matrix, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube-web

I would like to define a Quality gate such that allowed code smells would be 5 per 10000 lines of code. If it is greater than that then it should fail.

I referred this link https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Gates. I am able to create basic quality matric but the issue my lines of code would keep on changing with each check-in.

Can I reference other field (lines of code) with inside code smell matric. I can not hardcode any number for Warning/Error.

[image]

Atul Sureka

Comment: What your asking for is no possible. What is you exact use case ?

Comment: I have defined a criteria for code quality for my project. My criteria say if LOC is 10 K then allowed number of code smell would be 5. If number of smells are more than 5 then it should fail else it should pass the quality gate.

Comment: If you really want to do this, you should create your own measure : https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/API+Basics